# Centering the 3 dots of the setting or the search

Tags: java, android

As you can see, the 3 dots of the menu or the search button are in the top third of the tool bar. How can I center it?
If its relevant - some of my XML's:

tool_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar" >
</include>
<other views>
```

searchable.xml:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/hint_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/magnifying_glass"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.app.recommendations.content_provider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData=""
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" />
```

main_menu.xml:

```
...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/magnifying_glass"
        android:title="@string/hint_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
...
```

[image]

Comment: You can create a custom toolbar to make search icon center.

Comment: How? can I do that?

Comment: If you want to center search icon it will help you. Why should you want the three dots in center?

Comment: It opens to a menu. What do you mean by "Create a custom toolbar"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `android:layout_weight="2"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"`, I just setted the height to `wrap_content` and that made the toolbar lean mean and centered!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code of your too_bar.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />
           </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ToolBar with ActionMenuView.

In your toolbar.xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
          <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
              android:id="@+id/action_menu"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your MainActivity,

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ActionMenuView actionMenuView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
              setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

              actionMenuView = (ActionMenuView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.action_menu);
              actionMenuView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                         return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
                      }
               });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, actionMenuView.getMenu());
           return true;
        }
   }
```

Set ActionViewMenu's gravity to 'center'. I hope it will help you.